# Bitmap memory managemant Android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap

About my app: Taking photos, saving them to the phone memory, using BitmapFactory.decode**File**, loading that bitmap into one fixed size, not changing, image view.

Now, i know this was asked a hundred times already. I've been all over google\android's [manage memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) guide , but for my task it's kind of an overkill to manage and recycle different bitmaps, since i'm only  using one.

Here's my code so far:

```
    ..
    Bitmap bm_thumb = null;
    ..

    private void setPic() {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = imv_thumb.getWidth();
    int targetH = imv_thumb.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor; //was after decode bounds
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */

    bm_thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PhotoPath, bmOptions);

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    imv_thumb.setImageBitmap(bm_thumb);
    imv_thumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

These lines are not in the code, as they currently confuse me.

```
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mCurrentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmOptions.outWidth,  bmOptions.outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    bmOptions.inBitmap = bm_thumb;
```

Do I need to run decodeFile everytime I change my bitMapOptions?
Plus, If the decodeFile methods returns a bitMap, why do i need to also create one?
who am i supposed to give to inBitmap? i've tried both options, non seem to solve my OOM error.

My OOM started quite a long time after first installing and testing my app. My question is, how do I know I have solved the issue? If written correctly, will it fix its error, or do I need to select "clear cache" on the phone, and hope it will never happen again?

Sorry for the long post, I was really trying to remain focused..

Comment: have you thought of using a proper image handling library like picasso  http://square.github.io/picasso/ to handle images  --- instead of BitmapFactory

Comment: just a hint: if you have a photo (that is an image with no alpha) you should consider setting `Options.inPreferredConfig` to `RGB_565` You will save half of the memory.